# Is free-range veal available in the US?

Tags: veal, free-range

I found a [great looking recipe](http://www.finecooking.com/recipes/stout-cheddar-meatloaf.aspx) that calls for ground veal. Is there free-range veal or "rose veal" available here in the U.S.?

Comment: Meta discussion on off-topic status of sourcing questions:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ interesting discussion.  I agree that questions like "Where can I buy XXX cheaply?" don't add to the site. I changed the title to reflect what I really wanted to know; Is free range veal widely or otherwise for purchase in the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veal cows are male.  So the best place to get them would be from a dairy farm.  You know they have milk for the calf *and* they have little use for bulls.

[This article](http://www.russelnod.com/natural-veal/) lists some farms and source around the US.  In most parts of the US there are farmers that will try to treat their stock humanely, but they tend to be local organizations (for now).

Answer (score 4):

I purchase Strauss "Free Raised" veal in my local Whole Foods. I believe most Whole Foods Markets carry this product.

Answer (score 3):

The only manufacturer I could find that produces free-range veal in the US is [Strauss Brands](http://www.straussbrands.com/).  Through their website you can contact them to find where it may be sold in your area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about proper veal, but Prather Ranch Meat Company sells certified humane Vitellone, which is kinda like veal.  I think they may be slightly older. They're pasture raised and have a little grass in their diet.